# Access VBA Automation export to excel 2016

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to update some code that appears to not work correctly with Access/Excel versions 2016. The code exports data results to an excel file and generates a pivot table automatically. The file seems to generate, but as it goes to open, the error is received ---(MODULE NAME: UpdateExcel(Scrubber As ScrubberInfo, Queue As String) ScrubberInfo, Error Number: 9 Error Description: Script out of range, Line Number 10)--- on the UpdateExcel function, line 10 - automation error 2147697259. I have updated[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQYRd.png) the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, in code before this to version 12, for Excel 2016.

```
Private Sub UpdateExcel(Scrubber As ScrubberInfo, Queue As String)
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lstcol As String
    Dim UserSite As String
    Dim PvtItem As PivotItem

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
10
    Set oBook = GetObject(Scrubber.Doc)
    UserSite = DbFetch("Site", "b_users", "LanID = '" &   Environ$("USERNAME") & "'")
    Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(Scrubber.Table)
    oSheet.Application.Visible = True
    oSheet.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you placed line numbers on each line after your "10". I see several lines that could cause that error, but every one will appear as line "10" -- and then tell us exactly which line is raising the error..

Comment: Excel's Worksheets() methods expects an integer index or string. Consider `Worksheets("Scrubber.Table")`. And please show the *DbFetch* method.